# Formatting output from a dictionary in Python

Tags: dictionary, python-3.4

I'm having trouble formatting output from a dictionary. I've looked here and all over and can't find anything that shows the problem I'm having. I've only had a semester of python and sometimes find the terminology difficult to understand on this site and manuals.

My code:

```
for key, value in totalLst.items():  # totalLst is the dictionary
    print("{} {}".format(key, value))
```

I'm trying to format the output in 2 columns. The key is a string and the value is a float that I'd like to print as an integer. I reduced the format to the simplest form bc at least the code runs. I've tried using many of the formatting options such as `"%s and %d"%(key, value)`, and `"{}{>5}".format(key, value)` but nothing works. I'd appreciate any help.

OUTPUT:

```
Student Net ID      Final Grade
1{'U123': 27.923076923076923}
2{'U234': 393.84615384615387}
```

The 1 & 2 are put there automatically - they are not part of the key:value pair. I can't get rid of them or the brackets and colon.  It appears that the key & value are outputted as 1 item. How do I separate them and get rid of the brackets and colon?

Comment: You need an end-of-line character, `\n` at the end of each line that you print to print on a new line. As for the dictionary items being printed, I would need to see the actual dictionary.

Comment: Kevin, I'm not having trouble printing on another line although I can add the \n. I'm having trouble splitting up the KEY and the VALUE in the dictionary. I'm writing to the dictionary or I wouldn't have any output.

Comment: Can you post your dictionary? It appears that you have a dictionary containing values that are also dictionaries and keys that are numbers. So when you access your dictionary items you get the 1 and 2 as your keys and single item dictionaries as your values.

Comment: dicLength = len(totalLst)   
 totalLst[dicLength + 1] = {studentLst[0]:y}

Comment: You are correct Kevin!  I never would have figured that out. (Posting it got rid of my spacing so it's hard to read all smooshed together).  I changed the code to:         totalLst[studentLst[0]] = y    and it works!  Can't thank you enough. I spend an incredible number of hours working on it and never realized I had to go back to the input to the dictionary.  Learned a lesson.